# Passing a macro as a Plug option fails to compile

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix app, I'm working with several macros that I've written to add some additional custom formatting to the log data - however, I'm having some trouble getting the app to compile correctly when, using the `use` behavior, I add the macro responsible for HTTP access logging directly to a `plug` in my `router.ex` pipeline.

First off, here's a simplified version of the macro I'm trying to use:

```
defmodule MacroTest do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      require Logger

      defmacro execute(data) do
        quote do: Logger.log(:info, unquote(data))
      end

    end
  end
end
```

In my `router.ex`, I'd like to supply the `execute/1` macro to **Plug.Accesslog** as its `fun` option:

```
defmodule MyApp.Router do
  use MyApp.Web., :router
  use MacroTest

  pipeline :api do
    plug Plug.AccessLog,
      format: :combined,
      formatters: [ Plug.AccessLog.DefaultFormatter ],
      fun: &execute/1
  end
end
```

When I compile the app like this, I get the following error:

```
** (CompileError) web/router.ex:21: undefined function execute/1
  (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
  (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
  (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:198: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

However, I found that this will work if I define a helper function and call the macro there instead:

```
defmodule MyApp.Router do
  use MyApp.Web., :router
  use MacroTest

  def my_fun(data), do: execute(data)

  pipeline :api do
    plug Plug.AccessLog,
      format: :combined,
      formatters: [ Plug.AccessLog.DefaultFormatter ],
      fun: &__MODULE__.my_fun/1
  end
end
```

Is this the only way that I can accomplish what I need here, or is there something that I can change to allow me to pass `execute/1` directly to the `plug` without having to wrap it? If that's the only solution, it's not a big deal, but I'd prefer to avoid a helper function, if possible. Although I can't really articulate why this might be happening, I do appreciate the potential compilation complexities of passing a macro into another macro.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can do `fun: fn data -> execute(data) end`.

Comment: Does this work: `fun: &MyApp.Router.execute/1`?

Comment: @Dogbert the app will compile in that case, but as soon as the `fun` is called, it throws the error `function MyApp.Router is undefined or private. Be sure to require MyApp.Router if you intend to invoke this macro.`, referring to Plug.AccessLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need neither a macro nor a wrapper at all, just inject a function:

```rb
defmodule MacroTest do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      require Logger

      def execute(data) do
        Logger.log(:info, data)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and:

```rb
defmodule MyApp.Router do
  use MyApp.Web, :router
  use MacroTest

  pipeline :api do
    plug Plug.AccessLog,
      format: :combined,
      formatters: [ Plug.AccessLog.DefaultFormatter ],
      fun: &__MODULE__.execute/1
  end
end
```